# Parse JSON to C# object

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = @"{ ""rows"": [
                [
                    {
                        ""colspan"": 4,
                        ""id"": ""ContentPanel1""
                    },
                    {
                        ""colspan"": 8,
                        ""id"": ""ContentPanel2""
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        ""colspan"": 12,
                        ""id"": ""ContentPanel3""
                    }
                ]
            ]}";

    var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonData = json_serializer.Deserialize<Grid>(json);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

[Serializable]
public class Grid
{
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Row
{
    public int colspan { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to convert this JSON string to a C# object, but I am finding it hard because the error message is not very intuitive. Any JSON punters please help!

> ERROR Type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+Row' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Comment: As unintuitive as the error message is, it's even less useful if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: Do you have the web essentials for visual studio? http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Essentials-2012-released.aspx it has a feature `Paste JSON As Classes` which makes it awesome to parse

Comment: I have parsed the JSON using an online JSON raeder and the JSOn seems fine..

Comment: You might want to look at JSON.NET and the JObject/JValue features in it, that don't require that you create a fixed structure for your imported JSON, but rather uses dynamic structure values. It's much easier than mapping types exactly especially if you only need a few items out of the data. More info here:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we get:

> Type 'Row' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

The JSON with `[ [` shows a *nested array*. So either change the JSON, or make `rows` a `Row[][]`:

```
public Row[][] rows { get; set; }
```

Now we get:

> ContentPanel1 is not a valid value for Int32.

well...

```
public int id { get; set; }
```

vs

```
""id"": ""ContentPanel1""
```

Now: `"ContentPanel1"` is not an `int`. Make `id` a `string`:

```
public string id { get; set; }
```